# Facebook user migration to Business Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook Developer Apps for Website and Facebook Page Tab as not migrated as part of the "Facebook user profile migration to the Business Page". How to get access to the existing apps and get them migrated as can still use the app_id to access the apps and login using Facebook.

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs and tell them which user account should be added as an admin

Comment: Thanks WizKid, I have already done that.Awaiting their reply as my customers wait for things to get resolved.